Equivalence between Borel regular outer measure and regular measures
I am self learning some measure theory. Some sources like Evan's "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" define a Borel regular measure on a topological space $X$ as an outer measure $\nu$ on $X$ such that all Borel sets are $\nu$-measurable and for each $A \subset X$, there exists $E \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ such that $A \subset E$ and $\nu(A) = \nu(E)$.
Other sources like Follands "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Applications" define a Borel regular measure as a measure on the Borel sets that is finite on compact sets, outer/inner regular on Borel sets.
I saw another post Is the outer measure induced by a borelian measure Borel regular? where it was established that the common "from-above" outer measure induced by a regular Borel measure in the sense of Folland is a Borel regular measure in the sense of Evans.
I am working with another type of outer measure and was stuck showing the analogue with the following general setup:
Let $\lambda$ be an outer measure on a topological space $X$. Suppose that all Borel sets are $\lambda$-measurable and that $\lambda' = \lambda|_{\mathcal{B}(X)}$ is a regular measure in the sense of Folland. Are there any conditions under which $\lambda$ is a Borel regular measure in the sense of Evans?
To add more detail, the outer measure I am looking at is $\nu_{\mu}(A) = \inf \{\nu(E): E \in \mathcal{B}(X) \text{ and } \mu^*(A \setminus E) = 0\}$ where $\nu, \mu$ are measures, $\mu^*$ is the usual outer measure extension of $\mu$ by approximating from above by sums. It can be shown that under some reasonable conditions, $\nu_{\mu}' = \nu_{\mu}|_{\mathcal{B}(X)}$ is the absolutely continuous part of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. In my case $\nu$ is regular and $\nu \ll \mu$ so that $\nu_{\mu}' = \nu$.
